# Core Data storing arrays

Tags: swift, core-data

How can I store an array of strings in my Core Data model? I have tried setting my attribute type to Transformable and setting the custom class to `[String]` but I continue to get the error:

> -[Message setPrimitives:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000012f66c0

From what I understand, Array conforms to Coding which should allow it to be transformed. I've also tried setting the attribute to `NSArray` and various other things, but they all give the same error.

Comment: I recommend to use a regular `String` attribute and a computed property which maps the array to JSON back and forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was using a restricted keyword 'primitives' as my attribute name. I changed that and it worked perfectly.